# What math to use in this example?

Tags: php, math

What math can you use in this following example:

I want to divide a number by 2, but the result should always be a whole number.That means I cannot divide by 2 when the number is odd.

For ex.

when I divide 5 by 2.I want the output as 3 or 2, but not 2.5

Comment: Do you want both 3 and 2?or 3 ? Or 2?

Comment: it means i want to find both numbers by simple math. 3 and 2. answer is already provided under here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the math functions [`ceil`](https://www.php.net/ceil) or [`floor`](http://www.php.net/floor):

```
$number = 5 / 2;
echo ceil( $number); // Outputs 3
echo floor( $number); // Outputs 2

$number = 4 / 2;
echo ceil( $number); // Outputs 2
echo floor( $number); // Outputs 2
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/X3nCFo)

Comment: yeah but they put a 10 minute limit on accepting the answer, the weirdos. accepting in one minute now.. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
$n = 5;

floor($n / 2); // 2
ceil($n / 2); // 3

$n = 6;

floor($n / 2); // 3
ceil($n / 2); // 3
```